# Как насторить ssh подключение между linux server и windows client?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, сервер, ssh

Решил сделать локальный сервер для тестов (не на виртуальной машине), в качестве ОС выбрал ubuntu server 22.04. Накатил ssh, закрыл все порты кроме 22 (решил не менять). На основном ПК стоит Windows 10, пытался сначала подключиться через putty, потом решил через консоль (ssh). В винде вырубил полностью брандмауер. После долгих попыток подключиться - получилось только через софт на android и ios. При подключении с винды идет timeout error, что бы я не делал. Так как я в этом деле полный профан, точно утверждать не могу, но мне кажется что тут проблема с доступом на стороне самой винды. Буду благодарен за помощь и конструктивную критику:)

P.S. Клиент и сервер находятся в локальной сети.

Comment: ssh -v ваш_IP что пишет? ping до хоста? tracert до хоста?

Comment: ssh -v: `usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]`

Comment: А про пинг забыл добавить, он идет с Request timed out. 100% потерь.

Comment: Пинг понятно - порт закрыт. А ssh -v user@ip запустите. Например, ssh -v root@192.168.0.100:22

Comment: tracert: ` 1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  192.168.100.1
  2     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  3     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  4     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  5     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.` и.т.д.

Comment: Все так же: `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.67 [192.168.1.67] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: ssh -vvv попробуйте

Comment: А наоборот из линукса получается попинговать винду?

Comment: И ещё проверьте в настройках винды что тип сети стоит «Частный» или «Рабочий»

Comment: ssh -vvv - все то же самое

Comment: Разрешите ICMP на удаленной машине, чтобы пропинговать или пропингуйте обратно, как рекомендуют выше. При условии, что у вас на Windows не режется ICMP

Comment: Винда пингуется - 0% потерь

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема была в блокировке исходящих ICMP-запросов в Windows.